# How can I prevent HeidiSQL from changing the original query while saving View?

Tags: mysql, autoformatting, heidisql

I use HeidiSQL 9.3.0.4984, when I save SELECT query to View the program changes parts of the query from

```
`contactId`
```

to

```
`contacts`.`contactId` AS `contactId`
```

and from

```
DATEDIFF(NOW(),`birthday`) as `days`
```

to

```
(to_days(now()) - to_days(`users`.`birthday`)) AS `days`
```

and so on. This makes the query completely unreadable so I have to save the query somewhere else to be able to modify it on demand.
The question is: is there a way to save query to View "as is"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's MySQL (or MariaDB) converting the view code. This is a very old issue. You should comment there: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5159

In the meantime, you can use Ctrl+F8 (or click the button with the white sheet and the pencil) to reformat the SQL code in HeidiSQL. This works in any SQL editor.